# Full Charge Notification

Tags: notifications, battery

When my battery is fully charged I would like a Notification Sound. It used to make a certain tone.I went to my settings, and tried to find it  there but it gave me no information to do it. I tried searching Google but it was of no help. I look forward to hearing from you. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try an app for the purpose? On Google Play, a search for "full charge notification" brings up e.g. [Battery Full Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mboyadjiev.batteryfullnotification). I've just tested that app, and it works for me.

Comment: A pretty old app (last updated 2012). Have you tried it yourself (or only picked the first search result)? Does it still work with recent Android versions? Or maybe it would be better to use a more up-to-date app like [Battery Charge Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utopi.batterychargenotifier) or [Charge Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gt.com.chargingcomplete)?

Comment: @Izzy well if you now know that page of results you should try them for yourself, you own your smartphone afterall. (Yes I tried the first search result as most often they are good to go, it works for me)

Comment: *I* wasn't the one needing a solution here – so no, I won't test those apps :) It's just that "link only" without much details isn't considered a good answer on SE sites (we're not a "Google extension"). Thanks for the additional detail of having tested it successfully. That's what was missing from your answer (I've added it now :)